# No such sysroot directory: '/SDKs/' when compiling for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl

I'am getting this error when trying to install openssl for ios. I actually wanted libcrypto.a and libssl.a for ios. I tried following the steps detailed at [Compilation and Installation | iOS](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#iOS) on the OpenSSL wiki.

But after configuration when I run make install, it is giving all weird errors

Comment: You need to have Xcode installed and you need to run `setenv-ios.sh` (i think that's what the name is). The `/SDKs/` is coming from a path that's formed with something like `$XCODE_DEVELOPER/SDKs/` or `$DEVELOPER_ROOT/SDKs/` (or something similar). You are seeing the effect of the variable being empty. You also need to configure with `ios-cross` to ensure the variables are used. Things may have changed with OpenSSL 1.1.0. If you provide more information, then you might get a useful answer. Statements like *"... it is giving all weird errors..."* are not very useful.